# Python: how to host a websocket and interact with a serial port without blocking?

Tags: python, websocket, event-handling, serial-port, blocking

I am busy developing a Python system that uses web-sockets to send/received data from a serial port.

For this to work I need to react to data from the serial port as it is received. Problem is to detect incoming data the serial port needs to queried continuously looking for incoming data. Most likely a continuous loop. From previous experiences(Slow disk access + heavy traffic) using Flask this sounds like it could cause the web-sockets to be blocked. Will this be the case or is there a work around?

I have looked at how NodeJS interact with serial ports and it seems much nicer. It raises an event when there is incoming data instead of querying it all the time. Is this an option in Python?

**Extra Details:**

- For now it will only be run on Linux.(Raspbian)
- Flask was my first selection but I am open to other Python Frameworks.
- pyserial for serial connection.(Is the only option I know of)

Comment: Please name your OS. Are you using pyserial or something?

Comment: you can use for example `select.select` on Unix to poll serial devices and thus do the program even with a single thread.

Comment: Also currently your question is a bit problematic, it can be either answered with "Yes it can." or if it is not enough, then your question is too broad...

Answer (score 2):

Python provides [the `select` module in the stdlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) which can do what you want. It DOES depend on what operating system you are using though. So since you haven't provided that information I can't be that helpful. However a simple example under Linux would be:

```
import select

epoll = select.epoll()

# Do stuff to create serial connection and websocket connection

epoll.register(websocket_file_descriptor, select.EPOLLIN)
epoll.register(serial_file_descriptor, select.EPOLLIN)

while True:
    events = epoll.poll(1)
    # Do stuff with the event, 
    for fileno, event in events:
        if fileno == serial_file_descriptor:
            data = os.read(serial_file_descriptor)
            os.write(websocket_file_descriptor, data)
        elif fileno == websocket_file_descriptor:
            data = os.read(websocket_file_descriptor)
            # Do something with the incoming data
```

That's a basic, incomplete, example. But it should give you an idea of the general process of using a system like epoll.

Comment: What is `websocket_file_descriptor` and `serial_file_descriptor` ?

Comment: They would be the file descriptor (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) for the web socket connection and the serial connection. You can read and write from file descriptors. So if you use the socket library to create a connection it will return a file descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

Simply start a subprocess that listens to the serial socket and raises an event when it has a message.  Have a separate sub-process for each web port that does the same.

Comment: While that's one way to do it, it's not necessarily the easiest. All major operating systems support some kind of socket/fd monitoring. epoll for Linux, kqueue for *BSD/MacOSX, and IOCP in Windows. It's much easier to just give a callback to the WebSocket and the serial port, processing the data for each one as it arrives.

Comment: @aychedee - Since OS was not specified it is not clear which to use & personally I prefer a cross platform approach wherever possible.

Comment: It does seem like there's a missing library. One which does socket monitoring cross platform in a unified fashion :)